# Carregar objetos relacionados com @OneToOne

Tags: java, java-ee, jpa

relativamente a duvida na qual eu tenho é basica, mas anda tirando o meu sono.

Tenho uma entidade na qual eu chamo de Destination. Na entidade Destination eu tenho vários relacionamentos do tipo `@OneToOne` com outras entidades de forma unidirecional como abaixo:

**Destination.java** (Dona do relacionamneto)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="destination")
public class Destination implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_destination")
    private Long idDestination;

    @Column(name="appear_website")
    private Boolean dtAppearWebsite;

    @Lob
    @Column(name="description")
    @NotEmpty(message="O campo \"Descrição do Destino\" não pode estar em branco.")
    private String dtDescription;

    @Column(name="highlight_website")
    private Boolean dtHighlightWebsite;

    @Column(name="name")
    @NotEmpty(message="O campo \"Nome do Destino\" não pode estar em branco.")
    private String dtName;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_streetview")
    private StreetView streetView;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_video")
    private Video video;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_category")
    private Category categories;

    //Profiles of System. These profiles are all enum type.
    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_economic")
    private EconomicProfile economicProfiles;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_general")
    private GeneralProfile generalProfiles;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_social")
    private SocialProfile socialProfiles;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_trip")
    private TripProfile tripProfiles;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_weather")
    private WeatherProfile weatherprofile;
    //End of Profiles of System.

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_destination")
    @Valid
    private Set<Image> images;

        //Getters an setters...
```

Como pode ser visto acima tenho um "punhado" de relacionamentos tanto como `@OneToOne` quanto `@OneToMany`. Sendo que todos estão como cascade tanto para persistência quanto para merge.

Para demonstrar o problema eu rei usar o relacionamento entre **Destiantion** e **WeatherProfile**.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="weather_profile")
public class WeatherProfile implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_weather")
    private Long id;

    private Boolean heat;
    private Boolean cold;
    private Boolean winter;

    public WeatherProfile(){

    }
    //Getter and Setter...
}
```

Ok, vamos ao problema!

Na edição eu recupera meu objeto da seguinte forma:

```
destination.setIdDestination(id);
```

O mesmo me retorna o objeto populado com todos os relacionamentos. O print abaixo é do objeto destination:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que a duvida aparece agora. Quando realizo o merge no objeto as entidades que estão relacionadas são persistidas novamente no banco de dados. Creio que isso seja por causa do id dos objetos que esteja null como mostra a imagem acima.

Porque quando carrego meu objeto principal

```
destination.setIdDestination(id);
```

as referencias de outros objetos não estão vindo com o id atrelado?

Obrigado a todos!

---

EDIÇÃO

Atualmente uso o Spring MVC no projeto. Abaixo o fluxo de atualização:

```
//Entra na tela de edição de Destinos
@RequestMapping(value="/editDestination", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editDestination(Long id, Model model){

        //Inicializa o componente de paises
        List<Country> countriesList = dashboardFacade.getCountriesList();       
        model.addAttribute("countriesList", countriesList);

        List<Category> allCategory = getActiveCategories();
        model.addAttribute("categoryDropDown", allCategory);

        model.addAttribute("destinationModify", dashboardFacade.getDestinationId(id));
        return "destination/editDestination";   
}
```

Acima eu recupero meu objeto e coloco ele em um atributo para popular minha view:
            `model.addAttribute("destinationModify",dashboardFacade.getDestinationId(id));`

O objeto é carregado de forma normal! O problema é quando vou recuperar este atributo no metodo:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/mergeDestination", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView mergeDestination(@ModelAttribute("destinationModify") @Valid Destination destination, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model, @RequestParam(value="id", required=true) Long id){

        //destination.setIdDestination(id);
        Destination destinationId = dashboardFacade.getDestinationId(id);
        //Realiza os tratamentos para merge

}
```

O objeto destination vem com todas informações menos os id's das entidades relacionadas!

---

2º Edição

Atualmente meu metodo de gravação está mais ou menos como abaixo, ou seja estou setando atributo por atributo em minhas tabelas relacionadas com **Destination.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mergeDestination", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView mergeDestination(@ModelAttribute("destinationModify") @Valid Destination altDestination, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model, @RequestParam(value="id", required=true) Long id){

        //destination.setIdDestination(id);
        Destination destinationId = dashboardFacade.getDestinationId(id);

                try {
                    //Atualiza a Categoria
                    Category category = dashboardFacade.getCategoryId(altDestination.getCategories().getIdCategory());
                    destinationId.setCategories(category);

                    //Atualiza o Pais
                    Country country = dashboardFacade.getCountryId(altDestination.getCountry().getIdCountry());
                    destinationId.setCountry(country);

                    //Atualiza o Street View                
                    destinationId.getStreetView().setCode(altDestination.getStreetView().getCode());    

                    //Atualiza os Video do Youtube
                    destinationId.getVideo().setCode(altDestination.getVideo().getCode());

                    //Profile
                    //Economic Profile
                    destinationId.getEconomicProfiles().setEconomic(altDestination.getEconomicProfiles().getEconomic());
                    destinationId.getEconomicProfiles().setIntermediate(altDestination.getEconomicProfiles().getIntermediate());
                    destinationId.getEconomicProfiles().setLuxury(altDestination.getEconomicProfiles().getLuxury());

                    //General Profile
                    destinationId.getGeneralProfiles().setBeach(altDestination.getGeneralProfiles().getBeach());
                    destinationId.getGeneralProfiles().setCity(altDestination.getGeneralProfiles().getCity());
                    destinationId.getGeneralProfiles().setCottage(altDestination.getGeneralProfiles().getCottage());
                    destinationId.getGeneralProfiles().setMountain(altDestination.getGeneralProfiles().getMountain());

                    //Social Profiles
                    destinationId.getSocialProfiles().setAccompanying(altDestination.getSocialProfiles().getAccompanying());
                    destinationId.getSocialProfiles().setAlone(altDestination.getSocialProfiles().getAlone());
                    destinationId.getSocialProfiles().setChildren(altDestination.getSocialProfiles().getChildren());
                    destinationId.getSocialProfiles().setElderly(altDestination.getSocialProfiles().getElderly());
                    destinationId.getSocialProfiles().setFamilyChildren(altDestination.getSocialProfiles().getFamilyChildren());
                    destinationId.getSocialProfiles().setFriends(altDestination.getSocialProfiles().getFriends());
                    destinationId.getSocialProfiles().setTeenager(altDestination.getSocialProfiles().getTeenager());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que a *view* da sua aplicação não contém parte dos dados dos objetos referenciados por `destination` (ids, valores não editáveis, etc). Esse é um problema comum. Quando um usuário do sistema submete o formulário em alto nível o que ocorre é o seguinte:

1. O navegador gera uma requisição (POST) apenas com os dados do formulário
2. O servidor recebe essa requisição, que é interceptada e tratada  pelo Spring MVC
3. O Spring MVC gera uma representação incompleta da árvore de objetos com raiz em `destination` e repassa esse objeto para o seu método `mergeDestination`.
4. Quando você faz um `merge` utilizando a árvore incompleta (sem os `ids` dos objetos referenciados) o seu provedor JPA entende que novos objetos devem ser persistidos.

Nesses casos temos três alternativas:

#### Inputs hidden

Podemos armazenar os ids e valores não editáveis em *inputs* do tipo *hidden* na *view*. Esses valores serão retornados na requisição POST e os objetos serão reconstruídos corretamente pelo Spring MVC. Não sou muito fã dessa estratégia por vários motivos (consumo desnecessário de banda, possibilidade do usuário editar valores que não deveria, etc).

#### Atualização valor a valor

A segunda estratégia consiste em apenas alimentar a *view* com os valores que podem ser alterados e assumir que a árvore de objetos retornada estará incompleta. Para fazer a atualização devemos buscar o objeto original do contexto de persistência e fazer a atualização valor a valor:

```
Destination dest = entityManager.find(Destination.class, id);
if (dest.getValue1() == null || !dest.getValue1().equals(viewDest.getValue1())) {
    dest.setValue1(viewDest.getValue1()));            
}
```

Para situações em que os valores de uma referência não serão alterados, porém que uma entidade referenciada pode ser substituída por outra (e.g., substituir o país de destino por outro armazenado no banco), podemos otimizar o processo substituindo o método `find` pelo método `getReference` (que só retorna um *proxy* para a entidade).

```
if (dest.getCountry() == null || !dest.getCountry().getId().equals(
        viewDest.getCountry().getId())) {
    dest.setCountry(entityManager.getReference(Country.class, viewDest.getCountry().getId()));            
}
```

Adicionalmente, se você não se importar em atualizar apenas valores diferentes dos originais, você pode pular os condicionais e setar todos os valores diretamente no *proxy*:

```
Destination dest = entityManager.getReference(Destination.class, id);
dest.setValue1(viewDest.getValue1());
dest.setCountry(entityManager.getReference(Country.class, viewDest.getCountry().getId()));
```

Finalmente, para árvores de objetos complexas esse tipo de trabalho pode se tornar tedioso. Podemos aliviar nosso trabalho utilizando bibliotecas próprias para mapeamento / cópia recursiva de objetos como o [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/).

```
// Configurado com map-null="false" e o DozerProxyResolver correto
Destination dest = entityManager.getReference(Destination.class, id);
Mapper mapper = DozerBeanMapperSingletonWrapper.getInstance();
mapper.map(viewDest, dest);
```

#### JPQL / Criterias para update

Você também pode fazer merge de cada objeto referenciado (não utilizando `CASCADE`) e / ou utilizar `JPQL` ou `Criterias` para fazer os *updates*. Se você for por esse caminho tome cuidado com questões de sincronização entre o contexto de persistência e o banco (*updates* diretos podem deixar o o contexto de persistência dessincronizado com o banco).